# Javascript If or statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to write a simple JavaScript statement.

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400 ) || if (!($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 500 )) {
       $nav.addClass('show');
 }
```

Basically if user scrolls more than `400` from `top` and more than `500` from `bottom` I want to add the class `show`

Comment: Use `if (condition one || condition two || condition n)`. [MDN documentation for `if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Comment: Please state a question in your question. If the question why it doesn't work? In that case, you need to explain exactly why it doesn't work. Include information about any console errors you see. Also include information about how you tried to solve the problem, and where you got stuck.

Comment: It will not remove class at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 3):

To solve a problem like this, you need to do something called "debugging". There are many individual debugging techniques. One basic one is to keep replacing things with smaller pieces, or removing pieces, until the problem goes away, or you get an error you can understand more easily.

With your statement

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400 ) || if (!($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 500 )) {
   $nav.addClass('show');
}
```

you will get an error in the console. Open the console and view the error. (If you don't know what the console is, drop everything you are doing and learn that before you do anything else.) Let's say you can't figure out what the problem is from the error message.

In that case, replace the first item in the `if` condition with a simple `true`:

```
if (true || if (!($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 500 )) {
   $nav.addClass('show');
}
```

You will continue to get an error. That tells you that the problem was **not** in the

```
($(window).scrollTop() > 400 )
```

portion of the condition. Let's say that you still can't understand the error message, or figure out what to do about it. So next, replace the second part of the condition with another `true`:

```
if (true || if (true)) {
   $nav.addClass('show');
}
```

At this point, you will get a console error message saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

It is very unlikely that the initial `if` is causing this problem; that's obviously valid JavaScript syntax. So the problem must be the second `if` inside the condition. You can now jump to the conclusion that you do not need to, indeed must not, place a second `if` statement inside the condition. Remove it. Your problem is solved, without depending on generous SO people to identify every syntax error in your program, and you can move on and complete your project.

Comment: The questioner should also take some time to learn JavaScript syntax.

Comment: I fixed it to this

if (($(window).scrollTop() > 400 ) || ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - 500 )) {

But still it is still adding class even 500 pixels from the bottom of the page :(

Comment: Then you have a different problem with your arithmetic. Now you need to debug that. Open the debugger, put a breakpoint on this line, and examine the value of each of the expressions. I'm sure you'll figure out the problem in no time. This is how programmers debug their programs.